# curl to bing web site in bash from list

Tags: bash, loops, curl, for-loop, while-loop

I want to get host of a web site like filehippo.com:
What I tried is:

```
#!/bin/bash
AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1'
page=1
for line in $(cat /tmp/IpList.txt)
do
        REQUEST="http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3a108.168.208.206&qs=n&pq=ip%3a108.168.208.206&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&first=1&FORM=PERE"
        curl $REQUEST --user-agent "$AGENT" 
        let page=page+10
done
```

What I want:

I want to search in pages and get result, In this case I have 1 page but some of my servers have more than 1 pages..

Thank you